# Migrate .NET App to Win Server 2019. Security Exception: The source was not found.. Inaccessible logs: State

Tags: .net, logging, iis, registry, windows-server-2019

I am testing an ASP.NET application on Windows Server 2019.

The application is loading well, but when I try to log out, the error below prompts.

> Exception Details: System Security Security Exception:  The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security: State

I read somewhere, that we can edit permission rights in the REGEDIT folder as below, but I'm not able to save the changes.  A pop up message from Window Security "Unable to save permission changes on state. Access is denied."

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\State
```

Does anyone have an insight as to what could be done here?

Thanks!

Lyn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following steps can help you:
**Step1**:Open the registry editor and locate the registration key whose permissions you want to change.

**Step2**:Right click and select "Permissions" to open the "Permissions for RunOnce" dialog box, select the currently logged in user (such as Administrators), and check the permissions to be assigned (full control)

If the first two steps are failed to solve your issue, try the following steps:
**Step1**:Back to the "Permissions for RunOnce" dialog box and click "Advanced" to open the "Advanced Security Settings for RunOnce" window.

**Step2**:Click the change button to open the "Select User or Group" window and click the "Advanced" then "Find now", select the user.

**Step3**:Click "OK" twice, return to the "Advanced Security Settings for RunOnce" window, check "Replace owner of subcontainers and objects" is selected.